# I keep Inserting data to the same row

Tags: c#

Kindly help figure out what I am doing wrong,my datagridview is databound so I can't add a new row so I have create a datatable to be able to do so,there is a problem I can't get rid of,as I try to add data I add to the same row. Instead of the new row, please help get why this is happening or a better way to go around it.

```
public void getAllData(string stockCode, string description, string unit, string quantity, string costPrice,
          string saleprice, string taxcode)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("stk_code"));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("stk_description"));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("quantity"));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("uom"));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("discount"));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("tax_code"));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("stk_sale_price_one"));

    dr[0] = stockCode;
    dr[1] = description;
    dr[2] = quantity;
    dr[3] = 0;
    dr[4] = unit;
    dr[5] = taxcode;
    dr[6] = saleprice;

    invoiceItemDataView.DataSource = table;

    table.Rows.Add(dr);
    table.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why do you create Table columns every time you set rows? you dont need to that. do it once at start of your program. just like this.

create table:

```
  private DataTable CreateDataTable()
    {

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("stk_code"));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("stk_description"));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("quantity"));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("uom"));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("discount"));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("tax_code"));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("stk_sale_price_one"));

        return table;
    }
```

Initialize it to a DataTable that you will set to your DataGridView:

```
   private DataTable dt;

    public MyClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dt = CreateDataTable();
    }
```

Now, send your datatable to your method.

```
getAllData(dt, "1", "2", "2", "2",
                  "2", "s", "s");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

lastly, insert  new row to your Datatable:

```
public void getAllData(DataTable table, string stockCode, string description, string unit, string quantity, string costPrice,
      string saleprice, string taxcode)
    {
        int index = table.Rows.Count > 0 ? table.Rows.Count : 0;
        DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
        dr[0] = stockCode;
        dr[1] = description;
        dr[2] = quantity;
        dr[3] = 0;
        dr[4] = unit;
        dr[5] = taxcode;
        dr[6] = saleprice;

        table.Rows.InsertAt(dr, index);
        table.AcceptChanges();
    }
```

Hope this helps to you.

Comment: Thanks but am gettint this error {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} @ this Line int index = table.Rows.Count > 0 ? table.Rows.Count : 0;

Comment: the datagridview is databound,that said the content add are being pass from another databound datagridview(search form) thats where i use my getAllData method.when i try doing it your way i get an exception @ the line i indicated.Previously before i posted the question i was able to pass the data only to the first row,when i try passing again i end up replacing the same row while i have a new added row i was anble to set focus to the new row also.

Comment: that means you are not create your datatable before send to GetData as a parameter. your datatable  is null. you should create data table like this `dt = CreateDataTable();` before inserting a row. i tested my code before posting here. @home

Comment: where exactly am i supposed to send the getAlldata method,Hepl highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void getData(string stockCode, string description, string unit, string quantity, string costPrice,
          string saleprice, string taxcode)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("stk_code"));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("stk_description"));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("quantity"));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("uom"));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("discount"));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("tax_code"));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("stk_sale_price_one"));

    dr[0] = stockCode;
    dr[1] = description;
    dr[2] = quantity;
    dr[3] = 0;
    dr[4] = unit;
    dr[5] = taxcode;
    dr[6] = saleprice;



    table.Rows.Add(dr);
    invoiceItemDataView.DataSource = table;
}
```

Comment: do not require table.AcceptChanges();

Answer (score -1):

```
static DataTable MyTable = null; //store the table data;

//may be you means "AddData"?
public void AddData(string stockCode, string description, string unit, string quantity, string costPrice,
          string saleprice, string taxcode)
{
    DataTable table = MyTable
    if(table == null)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();    
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("stk_code"));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("stk_description"));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("quantity"));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("uom"));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("discount"));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("tax_code"));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("stk_sale_price_one"));
        MyTable = table;
    }

    DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
    dr[0] = stockCode;
    dr[1] = description;
    dr[2] = quantity;
    dr[3] = 0;
    dr[4] = unit;
    dr[5] = taxcode;
    dr[6] = saleprice;
    table.Rows.Add(dr);
    table.AcceptChanges();

    invoiceItemDataView.DataSource = table;
}
```